# программа на JavaFX не запускается и висит в диспетчере задач

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, scene-builder

Пишу программу на JavaFX в среде Intelij Idea

В один момент я захотел проверить, как она будет работать на других компьютерах.

Сделал exe файл с автоматическим добавлением JRE в папку с программой, там же создался и JAR файл.

Сделал это так:

File/Project Structure/Artifacts

Там отобразился мой проект. Создал файл MANIFEST в папке src проекта. Добавил Main Class

[image: Output Layout]

Далее во вкладке JavaFX добавил Application class, a  в Native Bundle поставил all.

[image: JavaFX Tab]

Нажал "Apply" и "OK"

Сделал build  - Build/build artifacts

Среда создала в папке out/artifacts папку с названием моей программы. Там есть Jar файл, exe файл, и JRE.

[image: Application Files]

При клике на exe файл, у меня программа начинает устанавливаться. После установки я  её запускаю, но она не открывается. Вместо этого она висит в диспетчере задач. Тоже самое происходит  и с Jar файлом. При двойном клике он не открывается и отображается в диспетчере задач.

[image: Диспетчер задач]

**Как сделать,чтобы программа нормально открывалась?**

**РЕДАКЦИЯ:**

[image: Java version]

[image: Manifest version]

**РЕДАКЦИЯ 2:**
Может при "упаковке" (build) моего проекта библиотека JFoenix не добавилась? тогда как её добавлять в ручную?

Запустил через git bash, результат таков:

```
$ java -jar CardApp.jar
javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/D:/IDEA%20Projects/CardApp/out/artifacts/CardApp/CardApp.jar!/card/resources/fxml/card.fxml

        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at card.Main.start(Main.java:25)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jfoenix.controls.JFXColorPicker
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(Unknown Source)
        ... 21 more
```

Comment: Какая версия java и что получилось в итоговом манифесте внутри jar?

Comment: добавил редакцию

Comment: в 10й версии javafx была уже разбита на модули. Смотрите как запускаются такие проекты.

Comment: @kentforth запустите `jar` через консоль и увидите что не так `java -jar file.jar`

Comment: @Tsyklop добавил результат в редакцию

Comment: не добавленные изменения в Git как-то влияют на build проекта в IDEA?

Comment: ну, видимо, не найден fxml файл. Как вы его подгружаете? приведите код

Comment: @alex не `fxml` а класс не найден.

Comment: @kentforth а зависимости проекта вы зашили в `jar`? По ошибке не может найти класс `com.jfoenix.controls.JFXColorPicker`, а значит в Вашем `classpath`-е нет этих файлов, а значит вы не скомпилировали зависимость вместе с `jar`-ом. Соберите проект не идеей а мавеном.

Comment: @ Tsyklop на первом скриншоте видно ,что в artifacts справа в добавленных элементах есть библиотеки

Comment: @Tsyklop вопрос не по теме, но все же, подскажите чем сборка через Maven/Gradle лучше,чем стандартная сборка  инструментами  IDEA?

Comment: @kentforth универсальность и поддержка. + Вам не надо заморачиваться с зависимостями скачивая каждый `jar`-ник на ПК. Если проект перейдет другому программисту то ему придется делать то же самое, а это время.

Answer (score 0):

**РЕШЕНИЕ НАЙДЕНО!**

В панели Artifacts справа есть колонка Available Elemеnts, там находятся все используемые библиотеки, я добавил эти библиотеки из колонки в свой проект для билда и готово)

[image: Available Elements]